# Electrostatics, using Gauss law to find electric flux through continuous body distributions

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image: List item]

While calculating electric flux through an **uncharged ring kept near a charge**, we tend to draw a spherical Gaussian surface that covers the ring by edges but while using the gauss law, we tend to take the entire circular region of ring as area bounded by it(just like we do for **circular disk**). However, the ring has electric field passing through it only in the ridges.So why are we taking the entire circular region in case of ring where in the middle there is actually no area?

Comment: I cannot visualise what you are trying to say about how the integrals are taken. It is too convoluted and so is the picture that you drew. Could you explain that in more detail?

Comment: It is probably a communication issue. The intent is probably the flux through the central region of the ring and not actually through the ring itself. The ring is probably assumed to have no width; so, it is not possible to calculate the flux on the ring itself.